# Mysql get missing values from other table

Tags: mysql

I have below query which will give me the ID which is in both the table.

```
SELECT DISTINCT IP.id 
FROM `table2` IR LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT id 
 FROM table1 
 WHERE item='xyz' 
 ORDER BY Id limit 728,91
) 
AS IP on IP.id = IR.id 
where IR.item='xyz' 
AND IR.idr='2295'
```

Now I need the missing ID from table2 which exist in table 1.

Comment: The left join should give you ID matching in both tables as well as ID in table2 that doesn't exist in table1

So, using right join join, you can achieve the reverse

Comment: There is rarely any point LEFT JOINing a table from which you select no columns. That said, as luck would have it, this is an INNER JOIN. Also, LIMIT without ORDER BY ia almost meaningless.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @Strawberry Edited for order by

Comment: @Krishnakumar right join is not working.

Answer (score 1):

You need an outer join that works the other way round. Also, you don't need a sub query. The following query will return those `id` in `table1` that have the desired `item` value and for which there is no record in `table2` that has the same `id` and certain `item` and `idr` values.

```
select distinct ip.id 
from      table1 ip
left join table2 ir
       on ir.id = ip.id 
      and ir.item = 'xyz'
      and ir.idr = '2295'
where     ip.item = 'xyz'
and       ir.id is null
order by  ip.id
limit     728, 91
```

NB: If you want to also add to that the `id` values that exist in both `table1` and `table2` (with the given conditions) then there is no reason to (outer) join `table2` at all.

Comment: Thank you for the help. The query looks perfect for me as well. But I'm not getting the desired result. I will look more into it and add more details if still I cannot fix the issue.

Comment: It would be helpful if could provide sample data and desired output for it.